# Android Wear notification: dynamic big text in title

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'd like to recreate the standard google calendar notification on Android Wear. It looks like this:
[image]

Where the 25 is the minutes remaining until the start of your appointment, which updates every minute.
I can create notifications with title, text, icon and background but I have no idea how to create big dynamic text next to the title. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, it is not dynamic text, just update the notification every minute
about big text, you use span to implement it, AbsoluteSpan may help you